# Is the random vector with independent continuous components a continuous random vector?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $X_1$,...,$X_n$ are mutually independent and continuous random variables, that is, for any $i = 1,...,n$, if $\lambda(A)=0$ for a Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_i \in A)=0$. Is the random vector $\vec{X}=(X_1\ ...\ X_n)^T$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}(\vec{X} \in A_n)=0$ given any Borel set $A_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda_n(A_n)=0$, where $\lambda_n()$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$?

Comment: You are talking about absolute continuity , not continuity.

Comment: Surely, it is very standard to call random variables and vectors, whose distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, continuous.

Comment: Hint to OP: If the $\mathsf{X}_i$'s are continuous, they have densities $f_i$ with respect to $\lambda$. How does the measure with density $\prod_{i=1}^nf_i$ with respect to $\lambda_n$ relate to the measure $\mathbb{P}(\overrightarrow{\mathsf{X}}\in\cdot)$?